# Add a header and footer to iframe?

Tags: html

I'm a total HTML noob. Last time I used html must have been using Dreamweaver over 20 years ago.

I got an iframe that loads my application. This is working fine but above the iframe I would like to add a header with an image and background color. Probably a percentage instead of a fix size to make it look good on different resolutions?

Below the iframe I want to add a small space with a short text.

How would I add that to this code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <style type="text/css">
      html, body { margin: 0; padding 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
      iframe { border: 0; width: 100%; height: 87%; }
   </style>
   <body>
      <iframe src="myapplicationip"></iframe>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out CSS background-image, HTML5 header and footer tags.

Using HTML5 tags you can start like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <style type="text/css">
  html, body { margin: 0; padding 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
  header{ background-image: url("img_tree.png");}
  iframe { border: 0; width: 100%; height: 87%; }
  footer{color:blue;}
</style>
<body>
 <header>
  <h1>Your header</h1>
 </header>
  <iframe src="myapplicationip"></iframe>
 <footer>
  <p>Your footer</p>
 </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I managed to make a fixed size header and footer in static position. However the iframe appears to be ignoring the header and loads directly at the top of the page so the header is drawn over part of the iframe. What would be a solution for this?

Comment: What about adding margin-top to the iframe parent div?